# C# Replacing filenames containing "." with " " but removing the file extension

Tags: c#, file, renaming

I am rename the files in a folder that contain a "." with a " ".
Expected result... Before: "I.am.testing.txt", After: "I am testing.txt"
Actual result... Before: "I.am.testing.txt", After: "I am testing txt"

The problem is that it also removes the "." for the file extension which is obviously a problem..

```
string folderPath = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxDir.Text).FullName;
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
FileInfo[] filesDot = d.GetFiles("*.*");

foreach (FileInfo fi in filesDot)
{
    File.Move(fi.FullName, Path.Combine(fi.Directory.ToString(), fi.Name.Replace(".", " ")));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to only get the name of the file, and then just append the original extension name to the end.

```
File.Move(fi.FullName, Path.Combine(fi.Directory.ToString(), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name).Replace(".", " ") + fi.Extension));
```

Comment: If you do this, you'll also need add + Path.GetFileExtension(fi.Name) as part of the 2nd parameter to Path.Combine

Comment: If you look at my edit from a couple of minutes ago, you can see that I added that. I realized after I posted it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I'm on the app on my cell phone and hadn't refreshed yet.

Comment: No problem @iCode I've done the same thing more than I'd like to mention.

Comment: @Conor perfect, I'm glad we could get it figured out for you!